# Best way to implement logging mechanism in iphone?

Tags: objective-c, ios, logging

I am new to App Development. I have a tab controller, where 3 views are attached. 
I would like to create a 4th tab, and provide the text view, where I would like to append/display the messages that are generated by other tab views.

Like `NSLog(@"...");`

I would like my own logger:

`myLogger@("...");` -> Updates the `UITextView` of the 4th Tab.

Kindly provide some idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a datasource class somewhere with a string in it. When any controller makes a message, append it to the string. Have the textview [KVO](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFgQFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html&ei=o6siUMWsA8yayQGIoYG4Dw&usg=AFQjCNEL6_EXLwjPTgWUPgZdI08Ik1xvmg) the string in the datasource and update itself accordingly.

Honestly though, you should use `NSLog` - it writes to a debug file all on its own.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible extension to Dustin's answer but you may find that [CocoaLumberjack](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaLumberjack) is quite handy. This gives you log level messages, but also helpfully you can write your own log message handlers which your 4th tab could gain access to using an appropriate datasource.

It is relatively simple to get started with it and the documentation is relatively clear, although you should note that it will replace NSLog with DDLog. As an added bonus it appears to be faster than using NSLog according to the [benchmark results](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaLumberjack/wiki/Performance).

Comment: I use CocoaLumberjack; you're right that it's better than NSLog